# How to determine that video was buffered in MediaPlayer on Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How to determine that video was fully buffered from URI(Youtube) in MediaPlayer on Android?
Is there any callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see when a video is ready for playback, use this callback.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html

```
onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
//Called when the media file is ready for playback.
```

If you would like to see when a video is 100% buffered, use this callback:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html

```
public abstract void onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
```

> Added in API level 1 Called to update status in buffering a media
>   stream received through progressive HTTP download. The received
>   buffering percentage indicates how much of the content has been
>   buffered or played. For example a buffering update of 80 percent when
>   half the content has already been played indicates that the next 30
>   percent of the content to play has been buffered.
>
> Parameters mp the MediaPlayer the update pertains to percent  the
>   percentage (0-100) of the content that has been buffered or played
>   thus far